# Ghostscript and pdfScale: Image quality loss when resizing PDFs?

Tags: image, pdf, pdf-generation, png, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert an already generated PDF from DIN A4 format to A5 using pdfScale (https://github.com/tavinus/pdfScale) which internally uses Ghostscript. It has about 20 pages and many of them contain .png images (mostly screenshots).

My problem is: in the resulting PDF files, the images look much worse and pixelated. This is the GS function that pdfScale uses:

```
# Runs GS call for resizing, nothing else should run here
gsPageResize() {
        # Change page size
        "$GSBIN" \
-q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER \
-dCompatibilityLevel="1.5" -dPDFSETTINGS="/printer" \
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
-dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=$RESIZE_WIDTH -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
-dAutoRotatePages=$AUTO_ROTATION \
-dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage \
-sOutputFile="$OUTFILEPDF" \
-f "$INFILEPDF" 
        return $?
}
```

I'm trying to change or expand on it to remove image compression upon conversion.
I've already looked at the Ghostscript documentation but I can't find the parameter that controls image compression for my case.

Does anyone know how I can control this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the rather simple solution: The quality of the images within the PDF stays the same using `-dPDFSETTINGS="/default"` instead of `-dPDFSETTINGS="/printer"`.

Too bad I couldn't find it in the official documentation. Thanks go to the creator of this gist: https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6390547.

Comment: It **is** in the official documentation. I admit it doesn't say 'if you use this you will get crap images' but the table of settings does note that 'printer' downsamples images to a lower resolution. Actually you are much more likely to see a problem with requantising JPEG images. You should use Flate compression instead of JPEG, unless you are certain your input does not contain JPEG images.